# Finding similar custom post type posts and linking them for standard wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Hoping you can help me with my problem.

I am trying to pull posts that have match the same word from another custom post type to the standard WP posts.

For example: A news post about "BMW M5 being announced with new safety features" and then a product page about a BMW M5.

On the news post I want to have a click out to the product page and pull through some basic information from the CPT and want to link the two by their name i.e post title of the CPT. As the "news" posts will have more than just "BMW M5" I'd need to do a kind of reversal wordpress query where it looks for all news posts which match the car product custom post type but on the news page.

I tried using a piece of code which I found on here that searches for similar posts using a modified query in the loop args but because I think it is meant to work for more words than the product pages offer it returns nothing.

For a stop gap I am looking for an exact tag on both but it is not ideal as it is open to error on the human side and would like to automate it as much as possible.

Here is the current code using the tags.

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
            $tag_ids = array();
            foreach ($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->slug;

            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'post__not_in'  => array($post->ID),
                'post_type' => 'games',
                'post_status' => array('publish', 'draft'),
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $tag_ids
                    )
                )
            );

                $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if ($wp_query->have_posts()){
                while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) { $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_field('image'), $size, false ); ?>

                    <?php
                    $originalDate = get_field('release_date');
                    $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($originalDate));
                    ?>

                    <?php if(get_post_status() == 'publish'){ ?>

                    <div class="hub" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $src[0]; ?>')">
                        <dl id="gdbinfobar">
                            <dt class="info_bar_title">
                            <h3 style="color: #FFF"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            </dt>
                            <dt class="info_bar_release">
                                Released on: <?php echo $newDate; ?>
                            </dt>
                            <dt class="info_bar_model">
                                <?php echo get_field('t_platform'); ?>
                            </dt>
                        </dl>

                        <a class="btn" href="<?php the_permalink()?>">View Game</a>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Please make it more clear, like I can think about my own   $wp_query1 ,  $wp_query2 etc and merging all as one array and then using those in a loop and 'post_type' => array( 'post_type1', 'post_type2' ) etc depending upon how clear you are with your situation, I can suggest some thing clear and you can also think about doing all these with pre_get_posts

Comment: I don't need to merge two loops. I need to search through a custom post type and display the post which its title matches the same words in another title. For example: Custom Post Type is called Post 1 and the WP post is called There is something new about Post 1. Then i'd want to show a link to that custom post type on the news post page.